# Google Sign-In with React app .JS Promise not initializing client_id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, react-redux, google-oauth

I'm having issues trying to implement  Google Sign-In in my web app.
It is a React app with a REST API Python Flask in the backend
Using google APIs plataform library to create the gapi object ( as per https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference),
it is suppose I do this :

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=init" async defer></script>
```

And after the platform library loads, , I should load and initialize the auth2 library:

```
function init() {
  gapi.load('auth2', function() { // Ready. });
}
```

To accomplish above requerirement I'm doing this

In child Component ClientOAuth.hmtl I created a promise as under:

```
static getGoogleAPI=()=>{

    if (!this.googleAPIPromise){
        //Loading the Google API into an scrip element in the page
        this.googleAPIPromise=new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
            window.start=()=>{
                // resolve the promise 
                // When this script is loaded a var called gapi=window.gapi is made available
                resolve(window.gapi)

                //Tidy up
                delete window.start;
              };
            const script = document.createElement("script");
            script.src = `https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=start`;
            script.async = true;
            script.onerror=()=>reject();
            document.body.appendChild(script);

        });
    }
    //We return the just created promise
    return this.googleAPIPromise;
}
```

Later I call that Promise in componentDidMount

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.getGoogleAPI().then((gapi)=>{
        gapi.load('auth2',( ()=>{
            console.log("trying to init the client_id in start") 
            window.oauth2 = window.gapi.auth2.init({
                client_id: '11111111111-aeimkno2v0lcs5u1d6fdk1o0uvtojpt0.apps.googleusercontent.com'
                // Scopes to request in addition to 'profile' and 'email'
                // scope: 'additional_scope'
            });
        }))
    })
```

However I get this error:

```
uO {message: "Missing required parameter 'client_id'", stack: "gapi.auth2.ExternallyVisibleError: Missing require…h-C23aWePw0rPNrzGe8eu-Ej8ZQ/cb=gapi.loaded_0:1:15"}
```

Could someone help with this , please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I changed the code as under , it works with a warning . I moved the code to componentWillMount

```
componentWillMount(){
   console.log("Inside componentWillMount")

   this.getGoogleAPI().then((gapi)=>{
        gapi.load('auth2',( ()=>{
            console.log("trying to init the client_id in start") 
            window.auth2 = window.gapi.auth2.init({
                client_id: '11111111111-aeimkno2v0lcs5u1d6fdk1o0uvtojpt0.apps.googleusercontent.com'
                // Scopes to request in addition to 'profile' and 'email'
                // scope: 'additional_scope'
            }).then( ()=>{
                window.auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
                // console.log(window.auth2.isSignedIn.get()); 
                this.setState({ isGoogleScriptLoaded: true})       
                });
        }))
    })
```

So the .then( ()=>{})  was needed. 
Now the React app is working, ....

Still Im getting an error in React  that should be because I'm not initializing the client id at the correct time in the React life cycle.

this is the error in ReactJS :

```
message
:
"Missing required parameter 'client_id'"
stack
:
"gapi.auth2.ExternallyVisibleError: Missing required parameter 'client_id
```

I wont leave the code this way.I'm expecting a better manage of the app STATE with Redux will solve my issues

***Python Backend errors and solution :***

For those of you who are getting these  errors in the backend, and I saw here a few people looking for responses to this error :

```
invalid_grant 
Malformed auth code.
```

Note that the short lived code needs to be sent to Google OAuth2 **without** "" .
I had to remove it before send it to the Google.

So if you send to Google :
"4/ERD456Yuip56PxaoTTzSncXkYocsxo1cE1FGLOHjScv07zb22nuoNTp0MpGv0KxnQeotiSLNIkyi0kSt9py8"

Google Oauth2 will complain and reject your request .
You will need to send

4/ERD456Yuip56PxaoTTzSncXkYocsxo1cE1FGLOHjScv07zb22nuoNTp0MpGv0KxnQeotiSLNIkyi0kSt9py8

Without " "

Hope it helps